# What is my error in this CSS float to column code

Tags: html, css, css-float

I just want to make the three articles in 3 columns, when I code it using dreamweaver on design mode panel, they are in three columns but when I preview it using live view or browser its doesnt appear in three columns, what possible code mistakes did i do?

**CSS**

```
.3col {
        left:0;
        float:left;
        top:0;
        height:100%;
        width:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="otherArticles">
    <article>
      <div class="3col">
      <header><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p></div>
    </article>  

        <article>
      <div class="3col">
      <header><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p></div>
    </article> 

        <article>
      <div class="3col">
      <header><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p></div>
    </article> 
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I reformatted your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: left & top needs position absolute? you want to use margin-left & margin-top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML IDs and CSS Classes can't start with a digit! Change `3col` to something like `column`.

Here's a [simplified example](http://cssdesk.com/xPM7r):

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks rjb you really made my day, I was trying to figure it out for almost a day, I didnt know that ids and classes cant be started with a digit. Thanks so much. It solved my problem

Comment: Good catch, @rjb! +1 However, the OP should still move the float to the `article`, as any future style changes to the `article` element will break the formatting.

Comment: I'd have to respectfully disagree. *Since the OP is using Dreamweaver, it's likely that it will add superfluous markup without his or her awareness.* More importantly though, the `<article>` tag is a generic HTML5 element and styling it (without a class) could prove to be disastrous. Consider what might happen if the author decides down that road that an `<aside>` is more semantic -- what happens to the layout, will it break? Nevertheless, styling an HTML5 element corners the author into using a HTML5 Shiv for older browsers while styling a plain-old `<div>` ensures the broadest compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Your `float` should be on the `article`.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kMnS7/

Be aware: only modern browsers recognize `article`.  You need an [HTML5 js shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make it work in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will certainly do that, I am still starting to use HTML 5 so this tip is certainly would be of help. thanks

Comment: My pleasure @user1129142!  As I mentioned in the comment on rjb's post, you should avoid just a class name change, as floating within an unstyled element (`article`) can break your design if you style `article` in the future.  Better to `float` on the containing element.

Comment: Hi Jason another question, is it possible to put two classes in one container? example <article class="column, wrapper">

Comment: Just remove the comma @ARGO, so `<article class="column wrapper">`.  Add as many as you need like this, just with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Give `float` to your `article` instead of `.3col` or remove `<article>` tag. Never start naming of `class & ID` with `numerical number` write like this `.col3` instead of `.3col`

Check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/AZ83d/

Change the name check this:

### http://jsfiddle.net/AZ83d/2/